# Weyl symmetry transformation and functionals using Noether's theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, symmetry, noethers-theorem

Let S be a functional 
$$S=\int{dt\left(\frac{1}{2} m\dot{q}^2-\frac{\alpha}{q^2}\right)} \;.$$
I am trying to apply the following transformations and find a conserved quantity using Noether's theorem, but having much trouble!
$$t\to t^\prime=\lambda t$$ 
and 
$$q(t)\to q^\prime(t^\prime)=\sqrt{\lambda}q(t) \;.$$
I don't really understand how to apply the transformations, but I do think that once that is done I can find $S^\prime - S$ and with that find the conserved quantity using Noehter's theorem. Is this analysis ok?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41265/2451